# Excel, one cell takes a value from another but want to subtract from another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

Currently F18 is =L27

I want it to equal that cells total (that cell adds tons of stuff up I'm working from something that have at work but it's old and thou I could just manually edit it with actual values be nice if could make it do I'm total newbie with excel)

but when get cheques as they go else where that number in L8 (adds cheques from day cells mon-Saturday) no idea what the formulas mean in these cells can post if needed, so need f18 to equal l27s total but need to subtract l8 when that has something in it

L8 has =if(Q8=0,"",Q8)

Comment: please post some sample data / screenshots, your question is very unclear now.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to change F18 to something like:

```
=L27-(IF(ISNUMBER(L8),L8,0))
```

This would check if L8 is numerical, if so, it subtracts that value, otherwise it subtracts 0.

Edit: As pointed out by @bdr9, a simpler version would be:

```
=L27-N(L8)
```

This returns L8 as 0 if non-numerical, or the value if numerical, and subtracts it from L27.

Comment: An even simpler way is `=L27-N(L8)`. The `N` function returns 0 for a blank cell or the number for a nonblank cell.

Comment: @bdr9 Cool, didn't know about that function..!